# Best Practice with Triggers - To combine or not to combine

Tags: trigger, governorlimits, bestpractice

Just a simple question on best practices - Is it better to combine simple triggers or leave them separate.

For example, I've got a trigger that updates a field based off of another field, and then a second trigger that unchecks a checkbox based on a certain condition.

I know governors come into play with triggers, and I do my best to avoid rubbing up against those limits, but I wasn't sure if they applied to each trigger individually, or as a group.

Thanks!
--Lisa

Comment: Its also a royal PITA to try and write test classes for new triggers when there are numerous other existing triggers on the same object! You wind up reviewing extraneous test results from all of the others firing throughout your test class while attempting to debug a problem!

Comment: possible duplicate of [General trigger bulkification - best practices](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/trigger-pattern-for-tidy-streamlined-bulkified-triggers

The above link is one of the excellent resource i lately read and one should avoid multiple triggers on the same object since that may lead to unnecessary running of code and unnecessary SOQL and DML .Also common practice is to bulkify your triggers and write proper test class to check working of trigger  for bulk records .

Maintain a separate helper  class for trigger on each object and multiple methods on the  helper class depending on logic .

Comment: I can't agree more -- there is no predictable order of trigger firing if multiple triggers on same object. This was discovered the hard way when triggers executed in one order on sandbox and a different order on PROD. The above pattern is excellent.

Comment: Hey thanks again for suggesting this method! I'm working on trying to implement it on our sandbox to see what it can do, but I've just got one question - does the actual manipulation of records happen in TriggerFactory.execute() or in the handler classes? (i.e. I want to change the value on a field in an after, and then update all of them at the end) That's the only information I'm not seeing in the example. I know this is probably a really simple confusion, but I'm still learning how this setup works, so my brain just isn't making the connection.