# General trigger bulkification - best practices

Tags: apex, trigger, bestpractice, bulkification

A general question asked from time to time on stack exchange is question of trigger bulkification.

Therefore I have 2 questions:

1. Which best practices are you using?
2. What is the best way to handle updates of more than 200 records? (In case of more than 200 records the trigger is executed more than once.)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Good question, but there are MANY possible answers, so I will just throw in my 2 cents.

The first and easiest way to '**BULKIFY**' is to leverage collections in order to save yourself SOQL calls and DML statements.

Here's an older, but still great resource by Jeff Douglass on utilizing collections in Salesforce.

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/01/06/fun-with-salesforce-collections/

IMO, I would say that leveraging collections is the first and best place to start in trying to optimize and bulkify your triggers.  I will now try to show a few examples of how leveraging collections can save you many Governor limit headaches.

**This code uses one DML statement *for each Account in trigger.new***

```
Trigger myTrigger on Account(after insert) {
    for(Account a : trigger.new){
        My_Custom_Object__c obj = new My_Custom_Object__c(Account__c = a.Id);
        insert obj;
    }
}
```

The example above makes a DML call for every account in trigger.new.  If this is a mass insert, you will run into governor limit issues.

**This code now uses one DML statement *total*, regardless of the size of trigger.new**

```
Trigger myTrigger on Account(after insert) {
    list<My_Custom_Object__c> objList = new list<My_Custom_Object__c>();
    for(Account a : trigger.new){
        objList.add(new My_Custom_Object__c(Account__c = a.Id));
    }
    insert objList;
}
```

This example moves the DML outside of the loop.  Instead you add a new custom object to the list inside of the loop.  Once you have gone through the entire list of trigger.new, you insert the list of custom objects.

**This code uses one SOQL query *for each Account in trigger.new***

```
Trigger myTrigger on Contact(before insert) {
    for(Contact c : trigger.new){
        if(c.AccountId != null) {
            Account a = [Select Id, Name, ShippingCity From Account Where Id =: c.AccountId];
            c.ShippingCity = a.ShippingCity;
        }
    }
}
```

The example above makes a SOQL query for every contact in trigger.new.  If this is a mass insert, you will run into governor limit issues.

**This code now uses one SOQL query *total*, regardless of the size of trigger.new**

```
Trigger myTrigger on Contact(before insert) {
    map<Id,Account> accountMap = new map<Id,Account>();
    for(Contact c : trigger.new){
        accountMap.put(c.AccountId, null);
    }
    accountMap.remove(null);
    accountMap.putAll([Select Id, Name, ShippingCity From Account Where Id In : accountMap.keyset()]);
    for(Contact c : trigger.new){
        if(accountMap.containsKey(c.AccountId)){
            c.ShippingCity = accountMap.get(c.AccountId).ShippingCity;
        }
    }
}
```

This example above utilizes a map to store all accounts related to the contacts in trigger.new.  The advantage here is that one single SOQL query gathers all the accounts.  You can then get the account easily within the loop without have to query the database.  You now have the same trigger with a sinlge SOQL query regardless of the size of trigger.new

I believe this is one of the best practices to optimize your triggers for bulk operations.

To take it a step further, there are a few more things that we can do to optimize our triggers.  One of the best practices is to only use one trigger per object.

Lets assume you have two specific pieces of business logic that you need to apply after an account is created.  The easy way to accomplish this would be to create 2 triggers on the account object.

```
Trigger myTrigger1 on Contact(after insert) {
    //YOUR LOGIC FOR TRIGGER 1
}

Trigger myTrigger2 on Contact(after insert) {
    //YOUR LOGIC FOR TRIGGER 2
}
```

This could work well depending on your situation.  What if you have logic in trigger2 that is dependent on the outcomes of trigger1?  There is no guarantee the order in which your triggers will run, so in some cases trigger1 will run first and in others trigger2 will run first.

A simple approach to solve this is to combine the logic into a single trigger

```
Trigger myTrigger1 on Contact(after insert) {
    //YOUR FIRST PIECE OF LOGIC

    //YOUR SECOND PIECE OF LOGIC
}
```

This works technically, as you can now control the order of the operations, and it is a best practice to have only 1 trigger per object, but still can be improved a bit.  Lets say for arguments sake this is a fairly large trigger, with a few different pieces of complex logic.

```
Trigger myTrigger1 on Contact(after insert) {
    //YOUR FIRST PIECE OF LOGIC
    //LOTS OF CODE

    //YOUR SECOND PIECE OF LOGIC
    //LOTS OF CODE

    //YOUR THIRD PIECE OF LOGIC
    //LOTS OF CODE

    //YOUR N+1 PIECE OF LOGIC
    //LOTS OF CODE
}
```

There are a few things that jump out that might be a problem.

1. All this logic is buried in a trigger and is not reusable.
2. It is very tough to test a specific piece of logic in the trigger. 
   You basically have to call a DML statement to trigger the entire
   trigger.

So how do we fix that?

We would want to move the logic from the trigger itself into a utility or handler class.

```
Trigger ContactTrigger on Contact(before insert, after insert, before update, after update) {
    if(trigger.isBefore){
        if(trigger.isInsert){
            ContactTriggerHandler.ContactBeforeInsert(trigger.new, trigger.newMap);
        }
        if(trigger.isUpdate){
            ContactTriggerHandler.ContactBeforeUpdate(trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap);
        }
    }

    if(trigger.isAfter){
        if(trigger.isInsert){
            ContactTriggerHandler.ContactAfterInsert(trigger.new, trigger.newMap);
        }
        if(trigger.isUpdate){
            ContactTriggerHandler.ContactAfterUpdate(trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap);
        }
    }
}
```

Handler

```
public class ContactTriggerHandler {

    public static void ContactBeforeInsert(list<Contact> newContacts, map<Id,Contact> newMap) {
        myMethod1(newContacts, newMap);
        myMethod2(newContacts, newMap);
    }

    public static void ContactBeforeUpdate(list<Contact> newContacts, list<Account> oldContacts, map<Id,Contact> newMap, map<Id,Contact> oldMap) {
        myMethod3(newContacts, oldContacts, newMap, oldMap);
    }

    public static void ContactAfterInsert(list<Contact> newContacts, map<Id,Contact> newMap) {
        myMethod2(newContacts, newMap);
        myMethod4(newContacts, newMap);
    }

    public static void ContactAfterUpdate(list<Contact> newContacts, list<Account> oldContacts, map<Id,Contact> newMap, map<Id,Contact> oldMap) {
        myMethod5(newContacts, oldContacts, newMap, oldMap);
    }

    public static void myMethod1(list<Contact> newContacts, map<Id,Contact> newMap){
        //YOUR LOGIC
    }
    public static void myMethod2(list<Contact> newContacts, map<Id,Contact> newMap){
        //YOUR LOGIC
    }
    public static void myMethod3(list<Contact> newContacts, list<Account> oldContacts, map<Id,Contact> newMap, map<Id,Contact> oldMap){
        //YOUR LOGIC
    }
    public static void myMethod4(list<Contact> newContacts, map<Id,Contact> newMap){
        //YOUR LOGIC
    }
    public static void myMethod5(list<Contact> newContacts, list<Account> oldContacts, map<Id,Contact> newMap, map<Id,Contact> oldMap){
        //YOUR LOGIC
    }
}
```

You have solved both of the problems mentioned above here.  You can now reuse your code.  You can call these public static methods from other places in order to reuse code.  You can now also segment your testing and test individual smaller methods when testing your trigger, as you no longer have to make a DML call and run the whole trigger, you can just test individual methods.

Hopefully this handles some of your bulkification/best practices questions.  There is actually quite a bit further you can go with optimizing but then we get into trigger frameworks and interfaces, but I think this is a decent start to some of the best practices when writing your triggers.

*P.S.  On a side note, this might be the kick I needed to actually start a blog as this turned out to be much lengthier than I originally planned.*

Comment: Like your answer! Great job! (let's collect more answers!)

Comment: One SOQL query isn't always possible as an "absolute rule". It depends on the relationships, what's available from trigger.new or trigger.old and what you want the trigger to do.

Comment: Not at all saying Only use one SOQL query.  Simply showing that you can (in these very simple use cases) replace many with one just by utilizing a collection.  The bolded wording above each example is not meant as a rule, but as a description of what the example is showing, I have updated the answer to try to make that more evident.

Comment: @sfdc_ninja - Please, do start a blog! Great post!

Comment: I agree with context-specific handler methods, and with organising those methods with method calls of their own. But I have had to guard against developers repeating code and multiplying SOQLS. eg: we want something very similar to happen beforeInsert and beforeUpdate, developer writes 2 almost identical methods and calls one from beforeInsert handler and the other from beforeUpdate handler. Or afterUpdate we want to do both X and Y a similar set of records, so the developer writes myMethodForX and myMethodForY, each of which queries the same object and cycles through it. Answer is: take care.

Comment: I agree completely.  If you look at my example I have the same method (method 3) being called from both `beforeInsert` and `afterInsert`.  In no way am I suggesting that methods cannot be reused, in fact, I am suggesting they should be.

Comment: What an awesome answer.  Thanks for assembling that fountain of bulkification knowledge.   ;-)

Answer (score 22):

First, here's a link to [Developer Force's Current List of Best Practices](http://developer.force.com/BestPractices?categoryId=a0e30000000GuoUAAS) for Logic  which has links to several articles that apply to bulkifying your code.

Here's a link to the [Trigger Pattern for Tidy, Streamlined, Bulkified Triggers](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/trigger-pattern-for-tidy-streamlined-bulkified-triggers) which is a good place to start if you'd like to implement your triggers as classes and have any and all code for for a single object in one trigger; something which I believe is very important to do whenever possible.

With all that said, here are the general guidelines for what I focus my efforts on when writing a more complex trigger:

Initially I usually collect data into `Sets` and `Maps` from `Trigger.new`, `Trigger.old` or `Trigger.newmap`, etc by iterating through `FOR` loops. I normally use Sets instead of Lists to avoid collecting duplicates. There may be times when I actually want to collect all instances of something. When that's the case, I'll use Lists. Once I have my record Id's of interest, I can later retrieve any related data that's of interest from Trigger.oldmap or Trigger.newmap, so don't necessarily need to capture all of it up front unless its needed to help me determine which record ID's are of interest to me.

I DO NOT PUT a QUERY inside of a `FOR` loop!

By having made these collections, If I need to query for information that's not stored in `trigger.new` or `trigger.old`, I can now run a **single query** outside of a `FOR` loop. I minimize the number of queries I make in a trigger by determining the relationships between parents, children, grandchildren and other related objects, then making a single query wherever possible.

Sometimes that makes it necessary to return my query results as a `Map` instead of a `List`. When that happens, I use a `FOR` loop to retrieve Lists of the different objects within the Map to put them into a form I can use. Example code below.

```
Map<Id, Account> AcctOppCustomObjectMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id,(SELECT Id, xxx FROM xxx__r), (SELECT Id, yyy FROM yyy__r) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :idSet]);

List<yyy__c> yyyThings = new List<yyy__c>();
List<xxx__c> xxxxThings = new List<xxx__c>();

for (Id accountId : AcctOppCustomObjectMap.keyset()) {
    Account acct = AcctOppCustomObjectMap.get(accountId);

    // the acct reference will have child or related lists for your subqueries
    // they will not be null, but they could be empty lists
    List<xxx__c> xxxList = acct.xxx__r;
    List<yyy__c> yyyList = acct.yyy__r;

    // iteration of the child or related records is possible now using these two lists
    for (xxx__c xThing : xxxList) {

       // if there's filtering I need to do or other work on the list, 
       // I can do it in a loop like below
       if(xThing.isEmpty() == false){ 

          if(xThing.xxx == yThing.yyy) xThing.zzz = acct.Id

          xxxThings.add(xThing);
       }
    }

    for (yyy__c yThing : yyyList) {

       // the same thing can be done for the other objects or both

       if(yThing.yyy == xThing.xxx) yyyThings.add(yThing);
    }
}

// I now have list xxxThings and list yyyThings pulled from the Map and sorted as needed
```

I perform all of my operations for creating, updating or deleting records before performing my DML on each object as a single operation. If there's more than one Object that requires DML, I've found its often best to call a separate class to do that with.

I try to avoid doing an update on the same object my trigger was called from. Doing that will cause my trigger to fire again. In that situation which is sometimes necessary, such as to reset a checkbox that called the trigger to begin with, the first thing I do in the trigger is test to see if that field's condition will allow me to exit the trigger (assuming that's the only criteria).

Additionally, I also avoid writing a trigger that requires a query be performed before it can determine if it needs to do anything (yes, sadly those kinds of triggers do exist).

Answer (score -1):

As far as best practices related to Trigger are concerned,following Points needs to be followed:

1. There has to be code written in a handler class and that should be called from Trigger.
2. One must write One Trigger per object,but can have separate handlers which gets called through the same Trigger.
3. Always go for bulkification.Instead of calling an DML operation on a single record,always opt for List of records.
4. Most important thing is first check whether the same requirement can be achieved using a workflow rule,process builder,flows.If not then go for code i.e Trigger.
5. Last but most important rule which is in General "NEVER PERFORM A SOQL OR A DML INSIDE LOOP".