# APEX trigger error on Account Level Only

Tags: apex, trigger, tasks

I'm new to coding and my developer friend and I have this APEX trigger to update a custom field on opportunities, based on recently created tasks.

However, we can't create a task on the account level, I keep getting an error.  I can create the task on  all other objects like Lead, Opportunity, and Contact, but not the Account.

Can you help me find out why?

```
trigger ActivityCreationLogger on Task (after insert, after update) {
for (Task task : Trigger.new) {
    if (task.WhatId != null) {
        Opportunity correspondingOpp = [SELECT Id, Last_Activity_Subject__c, CreatedDate FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =:task.WhatId];
        if (correspondingOpp != null){
            Task nextDueTask = [SELECT ActivityDate, Subject FROM Task WHERE WhatId =:correspondingOpp.Id AND Status != 'Completed' ORDER BY ActivityDate ASC LIMIT 1];
            if (nextDueTask != null) {
                correspondingOpp.Last_Activity_Subject__c = nextDueTask.Subject  + ': ' + nextDueTask.ActivityDate.format();
            } else {
                correspondingOpp.Last_Activity_Subject__c = null;
            }
            update correspondingOpp;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: could you add the actual code you tried on Account? And also the error you are getting?

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
Opportunity correspondingOpp = [SELECT Id, Last_Activity_Subject__c, CreatedDate
        FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =:task.WhatId];
```

will produce the error "QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject" if the `task.WhatId` relates to some other object rather than resulting in a null `correspondingOpp`.

One way to fix it is this (and the same sort of approach is needed for the Task query too):

```
Opportunity[] correspondingOpps = [SELECT Id, Last_Activity_Subject__c, CreatedDate
        FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =:task.WhatId];
if (correspondingOpps.size() > 0) {
    Opportunity correspondingOpp = correspondingOpps[0];
    ...
}
```

or another way (just for the `Opportunity` query) is:

```
if (task.WhatId != null && task.WhatId.getSObjectType() == Opportunity.SObjectType) {
    Opportunity correspondingOpp = [SELECT Id, Last_Activity_Subject__c, CreatedDate
            FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =:task.WhatId];
    // No null check needed
```

I suggest you start by making these changes and re-test with Tasks on various objects.

**PS**

A (untested) bulkified (see e.g. [General trigger bulkification - best practices](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices)) version of what you appear to be doing is:

```
trigger ActivityCreationLogger on Task (after insert, after update) {
    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Task task : Trigger.new) {
        if (task.WhatId != null
                    && task.WhatId.getSObjectType() == Opportunity.SObjectType) {
            oppIds.add(task.WhatId);
        }
    }
    if (oppIds.size() > 0) {
        Map<Id, Task> tasks = new Map<Id, Task>();
        for (Task t : [
                SELECT ActivityDate, Subject, WhatId
                FROM Task
                WHERE WhatId in :oppIds
                AND Status != 'Completed'
                ORDER BY ActivityDate ASC
                ]) {
            // Using first only
            if (tasks.get(t.WhatId) == null) {
                tasks.put(t.WhatId, t);
            }
        }
        // No need to query before updating
        Opportunity[] opps = new Opportunity[] {};
        for (Opportunity oppId : oppIds) {
            Task t = tasks.get(oppId);
            opps.add(new Opportunity(
                    Id = oppId,
                    Last_Activity_Subject__c = t != null
                            ? t.Subject  + ': ' + t.ActivityDate.format()
                            : null
                    ));
        }
        update opps;
    }
}
```