# How to resolve the apex Governor limit exceptions?

Tags: governorlimits, exception

i am newly move into salesforce. am facing some exception problems.
For example: In my Controller, lot of insertion and updation of data. whatever the Trigger i have inside my all, they are getting fired then am getting many SOQL Exceptions and Governor limitations.

Now Pls explain, How would you try to resolve this problem.

Comment: Do you read this : https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm ?

Comment: See this related question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices

Answer (score 2):

First you should be aware of Governor Limits of Apex. https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm

Next thing to know is how to handle them better and not to him them. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apex_workbook/Content/apex_govlimits_overview.htm

If you have lots of insertion of data, you better put them in a list before you insert them. Always remember to bulkify your data before having DML statements. Loops can be very useful for this specially FOR LOOPS.

I hope you get an idea for this.

-Oliver

Answer (score 0):

Definitely avoid performing SOQL actions within a loop, and as per previous responses instead review the best practices guides - links provided in previous posts - to learn how to use Sets, Lists and Maps to bulkify your database transactions to keep things efficient. Have fun!