# Received Trigger Error when inserting Records via API

Tags: trigger, error, errormessages

**Received Error below when bulk inserting lead records into system**

***LeadCompany: execution of BeforeInsert
caused by: System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 4
Trigger.LeadCompany: line 12, column 1***

**Trigger**

```
trigger LeadCompany on Lead (before insert ) {
   List<String> Accounts = new List<String>();
    for(Lead ld: trigger.new){
        Accounts.add(ld.company);
    }
    List <Account> acctlist = [select Name from account where Name in :Accounts];
    if (acctlist.size() > 0 ){
        for(Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++)
        {
            if (Trigger.new[i].Company != null)
            {
                trigger.new[i].Company__c=acctlist[i].ID;
            }
    else
    {
            trigger.new[i].Company__c = null;
    }
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the size of `acctlist` may be less than the size of the `trigger.new` collection. Hence the index can be out of bounds.

Instead of directly accessing `trigger.new[i]` you could build up a Map rather than a List of account names. Then you can lookup the corresponding Lead record using the map rather than the index.

Also, your SOQL select fields aren't selecting the Account Id.

As @superfell commented, unless you specify an `order by` clause in the SOQL query the Accounts could come back in any order. The order is highly unlikely to match the Lead order for `Accounts.size() > 1`.

Try something like the following:

```
trigger LeadCompany on Lead (before insert ) {
    Map<string, List <Lead>> accountNamesToLeadsMap = new Map<string, List <Lead>>();

    for(Lead ld : trigger.new){
        // It is possible that multiple leads will have the same account name in a transaction
        if(!String.isBlank(ld.company)) {
            List<Lead> leadsForCompany = null;
            if(accountNamesToLeadsMap.containsKey(ld.company)) {
                leadsForCompany = accountNamesToLeadsMap.get(ld.company);
            } else {
                leadsForCompany = new List<Lead>();
                accountNamesToLeadsMap.put(ld.company, leadsForCompany);
            }
            leadsForCompany.add(ld);
        } else {
            ld.Company__c = null;
        }
    }

    List <Account> acctlist = [select Id, Name from Account where Name in :accountNamesToLeadsMap.keySet()];

    for(Account acc : acctlist) {

        // TODO: Consider doing a containsKey(acc.Name) check on accountNamesToLeadsMap
        List<Lead> leadsForCompany = accountNamesToLeadsMap.get(acc.Name);
        for(Lead ld : leadsForCompany) {
            ld.Company__c = acc.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the other reason to use a map is that the query won't necessarily return records in the order provided in the :Accounts array.

Comment: I'm Not sure I know where to insert the map of leads to get this to process same account name in a bulk load.  I added after the close of the SOQL query and still it's only processing one of multiple leads with the same Account Name

Comment: @AndrewSims Support for multiple Leads with the same company name corresponds to the first `TODO` in the example code. You will need to switch to a `Map<string, List<Lead>>` to maintain all the Leads with the same campaign name. Then update the `Company__c` for all the Leads in that list.

Comment: @DanielBallinger still having trouble with this.  I posted the updated code above.

Comment: @AndrewSims I've refined the example code to keep a list of Leads with the same company name and then update them all based on the SOQL results.

Comment: @DanielBallinger You're a genius!  That worked perfect.  Now for my knowledge would you use a nested map in every case?  Why couldn't you use an object update statement?

Comment: @AndrewSims It depends on the requirements. The map made sense here as you needed a way to take the SOQL results back to the original list. The important part here is [bulkification](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices). I.e. minimizing the SOQL and DML statements.  This Map pattern is a fairly common occurrence in triggers. There is no need to do a DML update as we are in a before trigger. Any changes made will become part of the insert.

Comment: @AndrewSims If you consider you question answered there is a green tick mark next to the answers. This indicates to others that the question is resolved. You can still get further answers and make changes if required.