# Error Too many SOQL queries: 101 for trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I am getting this error Too many SOQL queries: 101 for this trigger when I tried to push it into production. Can anybody please tell what is wrong in the script below. I will really appreciate any help.

Trigger

```
trigger OpenAgingDetailsCount on NRProducts__c (before update) {

for (NRProducts__c np : Trigger.new) {

  AggregateResult[] results =[SELECT Count(id)total FROM Aging_Detail__c  WHERE  (Status__c='New' OR Status__c='In Process') AND NRProducts__c IN :Trigger.new  ];

  np.Open_Aging_Count__c = (decimal)results [0].get('total'); 

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "bulkify" by moving your query outside fo the FOR loop (otherwise it runs once per record)

```
trigger OpenAgingDetailsCount on NRProducts__c (before update) {

    Map<Id, NRProducts__c> results = new Map<Id, NRProducts__c>([SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Aging_Details__r WHERE Status__c = 'New' OR Status__c = 'In Process') FROM NRProducts__c WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new]);

    for (NRProducts__c np : Trigger.new) {
        if (results.containsKey(np.Id) && !results.get(np.Id).Aging_Details__r != null) {
            np.Open_Aging_Count__c = results.get(np.Id).Aging_Details__r.size();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Nathan, thank your for your response! I am getting this error now while saving the updated code: `Error: Compile Error: Didn't understand relationship 'Aging_Details__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 4 column 62` Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to figure out what the relationship name is for Aging Details... Go to the Aging Details object and click on the NR Product lookup field... it will tell you a "Relationship Name"... replace "Aging_Details__r" with the relationship name + "__r"

Comment: total is not a field on Aging_Details__c Object, I am trying to get the aggregated value so I tried this count(Id)Total  and I am getting this error: `Error: Compile Error: only root queries support aggregate expressions at line 4 column 62 
`

Comment: Ah, you just want a count of the aging details object... Any way you could make it a Master-Detail relationship so you could just use a Roll-Up Summary field on NRProducts__c to count the open Aging_Detail__c records?

Comment: We do  not have more Roll-up Fields available for the NRProducts__c  Object.

Comment: Ok, if it can't be Master-Detail, then check out the change I just made... you can use .size() to count the Aging_Detail__c records (again, you'll need to replace with your actual relationship name + "__r" (I was purely guessing)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22801/discussion-between-nathan-williams-and-carlos).

Comment: Ok thank you! I will try your solution and let you know.

Comment: If that helps, don't forget to mark this as the solution.  I'll also check back to see how your solution is coming along and if I can help further.

Comment: Nathan, I was able to save the trigger successfully (by placing the right relationship name Aging_Detail__r) but is not updating the field, it is just showing 0 after I update the record.

Comment: I placed a system.debug() to see the returning value and the result is null and it should be 4. please any Ideas?

Comment: ... and as a sanity check, you have >1 record where Status__c = 'New' OR Status__c = 'In Process'?

Comment: "the result" is null... what do you mean by that?  results.get(np.Id) is null?  or what?

Comment: Working now! Thank you so much! Have a great day! I learn something new today.

Comment: Awesome!  What was the issue?

Comment: the status was 'In Progress' for the Aging_Detail Record my bad :)

Comment: :)  glad you got it all figured out!

Answer (score 1):

You need to 'Bulkify' your query, so that the loop through the objects in Trigger.new only does one query. You can find a good resource, here [General trigger bulkification - best practices](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices)

Comment: Mark, thank you!