# Best Practices of Triggers of Task Oriented to Improve more?

Tags: trigger

```
================================TRIGGERS=====================================================

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm
EXAMPLE 1:
Simple Trigger:Use to insert the new object 
Trigger myTrigger on Account(after insert) {
    for(Account a : trigger.new){ 
        contact obj = new contact(accountid= a.Id);
        obj.lastname=a.name;
        insert obj;
    }
}
---------------------------------
Example1:BulkifyTrigger:
Trigger myTrigger1 on Account(after insert) {
    list<Contact> objList = new list<Contact>();
    for(Account a : trigger.new){
        objList.add(new Contact(Accountid= a.Id,Lastname=a.name));    
    }
    insert objList;
}
---------------------------------
Example1:BulkifyTrigger:
trigger Pratice on Account (after insert) {
List<Contact> clist=new list<contact>();
for(account a:trigger.new)
{
contact c=new contact();
c.lastname=a.name;
c.accountid=a.id;
clist.add(c);
}
insert clist;
}
---------------------------------
Example1:BulkifyTrigger:
trigger Pratice on Account (after insert) {
List<sobject> slist=new list<sobject>();
for(account a:trigger.new)
{
contact c=new contact();
c.lastname=a.name;
c.accountid=a.id;
slist.add(c);
Opportunity Opp=new Opportunity();
Opp.name=a.name;
Opp.Stagename='Closed won';
Opp.closedate=date.today();
slist.add(opp);
}
insert slist;
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Task:Before Save record insert field and Insert New Object and Update some fields
trigger beforeinserfieldnewobj on Account (before insert,after insert){
for(account acc:trigger.new)
{
if(trigger.isinsert&&trigger.isbefore)
{
acc.Description='day hot!';
}
if(trigger.isafter)
{
contact con=new contact();
con.lastname=acc.name;
con.description=acc.description;
con.accountid=acc.id;
insert con;
}
}
}
----------------------------------
Task:Only it Accepts India
trigger practice on Account (before update){
for(account a:trigger.new)
if(trigger.isupdate)
{
if(a.name!='India')
a.adderror('Only it accepts india');
}
}
------------------------------------------------
Task:contact phone update to account
trigger phupdate on Contact (after insert,after update) {
   list<account> acclist=new list<account>();
   list<id> lid=new list<id>();
   for(contact c:trigger.new)
   {
   lid.add(c.accountid);
   }
   map<id,account> mapaccounts=new map<id,account>([select id,name,phone from account where id in:lid]);
   for(contact c:trigger.new)
   {
   account a=mapaccounts.get(c.accountid);
   if(a!=null)
   {
   a.phone=c.MobilePhone;
   acclist.add(a);
   }
   }
   update acclist;
}
-------------------------------------------------------
Task:Adding two Object in one list SObject
trigger bestpracticeoftriggers on Account (after insert) {
list<sobject> slist=new list<sobject>();
for(account a:trigger.new)
{
contact con=new contact();
con.lastname=a.name;
slist.add(con);
lead ld=new lead();
ld.lastname=a.name;
ld.status='closed converted';
ld.company='Apple';
slist.add(ld);
}
insert slist;
}
-----------------------
Task:No.of Cases
trigger updateacccounts on Contact (after insert,after delete,after undelete) {
set<id> plist=new set<id>();
list<account> acclist=new list<account>();
if(trigger.isinsert || trigger.isundelete){
for(contact c:trigger.new)
{
plist.add(c.accountid);
}
}
if(trigger.isdelete){
for(contact c1:trigger.old)
{
plist.add(c1.accountid);
}
}
for(account acc:[select id,name,No_of_Contacts__c,(select id,name from contacts) from account where id=:plist])
{
acc.No_of_Contacts__c=acc.contacts.size();
acclist.add(acc);
}
try
{
update acclist;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.debug('Exception '+e.getMessage());
}
}

TestClass:
@istest
public class updateacccounts_Tc{
static testmethod void updateacccounts_Tc()
{
account acc=new account(name='xxxx',No_of_Contacts__c=1233);
insert acc;
contact c=new contact(lastname='xxxx',accountid=acc.id);
insert c;
contact c1=[select id,lastname from contact where id=:c.id];
delete c1;
}
}

---------------------------------------
Task:Triggers With Using Map:
trigger UpdateContactsPhoneWenAccEditPhone on Account (after update) {
map<string,Account> maccounts= new map<string,Account>();
List<contact> cons= new list<contact>();
for(Account acc:trigger.new){
maccounts.put(acc.id,acc);
}
for(contact c:[select id,Name,Accountid from contact where Accountid != null AND 
Accountid in: maccounts.keyset()]){
if(maccounts.containskey(c.accountid)){
c.phone= maccounts.get(c.accountid).Phone;
cons.add(c);
}
}
update cons;
}
-------------------------------------------------
Task:MailingCity Maps to ShippingCity
Trigger myTrigger on Contact(before insert) {
    map<Id,Account> accountMap = new map<Id,Account>();
    for(Contact c : trigger.new){
        accountMap.put(c.AccountId, null);
    }
    accountMap.remove(null);
    accountMap.putAll([Select Id, Name, ShippingCity From Account Where Id In : accountMap.keyset()]);
    for(Contact c : trigger.new){
        if(accountMap.containsKey(c.AccountId)){
            c.mailingcity= accountMap.get(c.AccountId).ShippingCity;
        }
    }
}
---------------------------------
Task:PreventLeadDeletion:
trigger PreventLeadDeletion on Lead (before delete) {
    for(Lead l :trigger.old){
        l.addError('You can not delete this record.');
    }
}
-------------------------------------------
Task:PreventLeadEmailChanging:
trigger PreventLeadEmailChanging on Lead (before update) {
    for(Lead l :trigger.new){
        if(l.Email!=trigger.oldMap.get(l.id).Email && trigger.oldMap.get(l.id).Email!=null){
            l.Email.addError('You can not change email.');
        }
    }
}
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Task:This is not efficient code.It will not work for bulk records:
trigger PreventAccountDeletion on Account (before delete) {
    for(Account a:trigger.old){
        List<Contact> cons = [select id,name from Contact where AccountId =: a.id];
        if(!cons.isEmpty()){
            a.addError('You can not delete this Account it contains Contacts');
        }
    }
}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Task:Populate contact description with modified user name when user updates contact.
trigger ContactBeforeUpdate on Contact (before update) {
// Trigger.New hold new version of Contacts
for(Contact contact: Trigger.new){
contact.Description = 'Contact updated successfully by '+ userInfo.getUserName() ;
}
// No Need to write DML statement, trigger. New will be take care.
}
------------------------------------------
Task:Preventdeletion on Account:
trigger preventdeletion on Account (before delete) {
for(Account a:trigger.old){
list<contact> con = [select id,name from contact where AccountId =: a.id];
list<Opportunity> opp = [select id,name from opportunity where AccountId =: a.id];
if(!con.isEmpty()){
a.addError('you cannot delete Account it contains contact');
}
if(!opp.isEmpty()){
a.addError('you cannot delete Account it contains opportunity');
}
}
}
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Task: Throw an error whenever the user try to delete the contact which is not associated 
to account
trigger contactBeforeDelete on Contact(before delete){
for(Contact contact: trigger.old){
if(contact.accountId == null){
contact.addError('Hey! You are not authorized to perform this action.');
}
}
}
----------------------------------------------------
Concept:Invoking Apex Class to Triggers:
Trigger::
trigger triggertoapex on Account (before insert) {
for(account a:trigger.new)
{
triggertoapex ta=new triggertoapex();
ta.triggertoapexmethod(a);
}
}
Apex::
public class triggertoapex{
public void triggertoapexmethod(account a)
{
a.name='Mr/Mrs-'+a.name;
a.phone='+91'+a.phone;
}
}
--------------------------------------------------------
Task:Update AccountStatus Child from Parent
trigger AccountStatus on Opportunity (before insert, before update){

  List<ID> OppIds = New List<ID>();

  for(Opportunity a : Trigger.new){
    if(a.stagename == 'Closed Won' ){
      OppIds.add(a.accountID);
    }
  }

  List<Account> oppList = [SELECT id, account_status_2__c FROM Account WHERE id in :OppIds];
  for(integer i = 0 ; i < oppList.size(); i++){
     oppList[i].account_status_2__c = 'Current';
  }

  update oppList;
}
----------------------------------------------------
Task:Invoking Class to trigger and test class 
trigger accnameclsdatemodifydate on Opportunity (before insert,before update) {
if(trigger.isbefore && trigger.isinsert){
  oppnameupdate.oppnameupdatewithacnamelastmodifyclsdate(trigger.new);
}
if(trigger.isbefore && trigger.isupdate){
  oppnameupdate.oppnameupdatewithacnamelastmodifyclsdate(trigger.new);
}
}

public class oppnameupdate{
  public static void oppnameupdatewithacnamelastmodifyclsdate(list<opportunity> opp){
     set<id> accountid= new set<id>();
     set<id>ownerid= new set<id>();
     string opname;
     for(opportunity opp1 :opp){
          accountid.add(opp1.accountid);
          ownerid.add(opp1.ownerid);
     }
   map<id,account> accmap= new map<id,account>([select name,id from account where id in:accountid]);
   map<id,user> usermap= new map<id,user>([select lastmodifiedby.name,id from user where id in:ownerid]);

   for(opportunity opp2:opp){
       opname=accmap.get(opp2.accountid).name+' '+opp2.closedate+' '+usermap.get(opp2.ownerid).lastmodifiedby.name;
       opp2.name=opname;
   }
  }
}

@isTest
private class testoppnameupdate{
  private static  testmethod void testopportunityviaDML(){
   oppnameupdate opp=new oppnameupdate();

   account ac=new account();
   ac.name='sampleac';
   insert ac;
   list<opportunity> oppl= new list<opportunity>(); 
   opportunity op=new opportunity();
   op.name='sampleopp';
   op.accountid=ac.id;
   op.StageName='Prospecting';
   op.closedate=system.today();

   oppl.add(op);
   insert oppl;
   update oppl;

  }
  }
------------------------------------------
>>>Insert Lead Task is Created:::
trigger newLeadTask on Lead (after Insert) {
 List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
 for(Lead l : trigger.new){
 Task t = new Task(Subject = 'Contact Lead',
 WhoId = l.id,
 Status = 'Not Started', 
 OwnerId = l.OwnerId);
 if(l.LastName <> 'Elephantman'){
 t.ActivityDate = Date.today()+7;
 }else{
 t.ActivityDate = Date.today()+1;
 }
 taskList.add(t);
 }
 insert taskList; 
}
>>>TestClass:::
@isTest //indicates this is a test so that the code below doesn't count against our quota
private class testLead{
 private static testmethod void testLeadActivity(){
 //insert a random (non Elephantman lead)
 Lead l = new Lead(LastName = 'Randomname', Company = 'ABC, Inc.');
 insert l;

 List<Task> taskList = [SELECT id, ActivityDate from Task WHERE whoId = :l.id];
 System.assertEquals(1,taskList.size());
 System.assertEquals(Date.today()+7,taskList[0].ActivityDate);

 //insert an Elephantman lead
 Lead eMan = new Lead(LastName = 'Elephantman', Company = 'ABC, Inc.');
 insert eMan;

 List<Task> eManTaskList = [SELECT id, ActivityDate from Task WHERE whoId = :eMan.id];
 System.assertEquals(1,eManTaskList.size());
 System.assertEquals(Date.today()+1,eManTaskList[0].ActivityDate);
 }
}
==============================TEST CLASSES====================================================
Test Classes:
Before you can deploy Apex or package it for the Force.com AppExchange, the following must be true.
-At least 75% of your Apex code must be covered by unit tests, and all of those tests must complete successfully.
-Every trigger must have some test coverage.
-All classes and triggers must compile successfully.

----------------------------------
Task:Basic Class for Hello
Apex::
public class Hello {
public static void sayYou() {
System.debug( 'You' );
}
public void sayMe() {
System.debug( 'Me' );
}
public void saysan() {
System.debug( 'san' );
}
public void azeemhai() {
System.debug( 'hai' );
}
}
TestClass::
@istest
public class Hello_TC{
static testmethod void Hello()
{
Hello.SayYou();
Hello H=new Hello();
H.sayMe();
H.azeemhai();
H.saysan();
}
}
-----------------------------------
Task:AccountLatestRecord
Apex::
public class AccountLatestRecord 
{
public recentlyviewed acc{get;set;}
public void Latest()
{
acc=[select id from recentlyviewed where type='account' limit 1 ];
}
}
TestClass::
@istest
public class AccountLatestRecord_TC{
static testmethod void acct(){
recentlyviewed rv=new recentlyviewed();
AccountLatestRecord al=new AccountLatestRecord();
al.Latest();
}
}



==============================BATCH APEX=====================================================

global class gazu implements database.batchable<sobject>
{
global database.querylocator start(database.batchablecontext bc)
{
string sn='closed won';
string query='select id,name,stagename from opportunity where stagename=:sn';
return database.getquerylocator(query);
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, list<opportunity> opplist){
for(opportunity opp:opplist)
{
opp.description='Your Stage is in Progress';
string val1=opp.name;
string val2='-';
string val3='Update';
string result='';
result=string.valueof(val1)+string.valueof(val2)+string.valueof(val3);
opp.name=string.valueof(result);
}
update opplist;
}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}
}
//call like this in developer console:
//gaz g=new gaz();
//Database.executeBatch(g);
```

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices

Answer (score 1):

This will help you:

**DML statements:**
In example 1, you are using a DML statement inside a loop. You can execute only 150 DML statements in a transaction. If the loop runs more than 150 times, your code will hit the governor limit and the entire transaction will fail. You must always add the objects in a list and then perform the DML on that. For example, everything is fine in *Example 1 : Bulkified trigger*.

**SOQL:**
Just like DML, you can only issue 100 SOQL statements. Hence, avoid writing them inside a loop.

**Avoid multiple triggers:**
It's always better to avoid multiple trigger on an object. Hence, it is advisable to write all your logic in a handler class and call the methods accordingly from the trigger. You can use trigger context variable to identify methods that should run before or after record is saved in the database.

**Use of collections:**
Use of Sets, Maps and Lists is also a best practice as it streamlines the process and can substantially help writing efficient Apex code and avoid governor limits.

**Use of SOQL for loop:**
Use SOQL for loop to get efficient performance. Like this:

```
for (List<Account> acct : [SELECT id, name FROM account limit 100]) {
// Your code here
}
```

**Use Limits class** *(Very important)*:
Use Limits class to keep a track of how much resource you have utilized and how much is still left in a particular transactions.
Additionally, you can also enable Apex governor limit warning emails by visiting your User settings.

**Test Coverage:**
Test coverage is also a very significant parameter. Always write test classes for your apex code. Although 75% coverage is enough for deployment but aim for 100% always.

**Avoid Hardcoding:**
NEVER HARDCODE ID in apex. Everything will fail if you deploy the code from one org to another because the Id may not exist there.

**Proper Use Of Asynchronous Apex:**
Learn how and when to use Asynchronous apex, that includes Batch Apex, Queueable apex and Future methods. They have a great utility and provide an alternative to perform operation without letting users know about that.

These principles should be incorporated into your Apex code in order to write efficient, scalable code and also go through this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices).

Comment: heisenberg, this is a link only answer. It's preferred that you provide at least a few details from the link and give credit to the author in the event the link should disappear at some point in the future. I suggest you update your answer with more information before it goes into the review queue for possible deletion.

Comment: @crmprogdev - Thanks for pointing this out. I updated my answer.