# ERROR - Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List

Tags: apex, trigger

UPDATE:

```
trigger ListCheck on Setup__c (after update)
{
   list<Id> empIdList = new list<Id>(); 
   for(Setup__c s : trigger.new)
    {
      empIdList.add(s.EmpId__c);

    }

    list<Employee__c> empList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Employee__c WHERE Id in : empIdList];

    if(empList.size() > 0){
     for(EMployee__c e: empList){
       e.status = 'completed'; 
       e.last_num__c = empIdList.Id;  //<<<<<error
      }
    update empList;
   }
}
```

Error:

> Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List

I'm getting this error message : I have searched before I'm posting and could not find the solution to my issue, please have a look below.

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

```
trigger ListCheck on Setup__c (after update)
{
    for(Setup__c s : trigger.new)
    {
        Employee__c emp = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Employee__c WHERE Id =: s.Id];

        if(emp != null)
        {
          //do more work.... 
        }               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 trigger ListCheck on Setup__c (after update)
{
   list<Id> empIdList = new list<Id>(); 
   for(Setup__c s : trigger.new)
    {
      empIdList.add(s.EmpId__c);

    }

    list<Employee__c> empList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Employee__c WHERE Id in : empIdList];

    if(empList.size() > 0){
     for(EMployee__c e: empList){
       e.status = 'completed'; 
      }
    update empList;
   }
}
```

Comment: inside for loop is it safe to use the `update` ? for an example: `for(EMployee__c e:empList){ e.status = 'completed'; update e;` ?

Comment: @Abu Hamzah u need to do outside for loop.I just updated

Comment: Thanks I have updated my question, getting an error please have  look at my question.

Comment: Are you trying to update e.last_Num__c  with  employee Id (e.Id) to..if so then u need to update e.last_num___c = e.Id;

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the query is incorrect,

```
Employee__c emp = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Employee__c WHERE Id =: s.Id];
```

the error is due to the fact that you are querying within Employee__c object and sending id of Setup__c. As there are no records, the resultant query is unable to assign the result into "Employee__c emp"

So, you should revisit, how you want to retrieve employees using Setup__C id (probably some relationship that you have setup there)

Secondly, it is incorrect to use a query within For loop, as it can lead to breach of governor limits. Suggest you to refer:-

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code

[General trigger bulkification - best practices](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and I do understand that if there is no match then why throwing the error? am I missing something?

Comment: Employee__c emp = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Employee__c WHERE Id =: s.Id];

This code tries to take the first item from list and assign it to the variable, as the list (query result) is null, hence the error.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the logic here but just fyi I'm not using a `List` of records here just get me the record if match otherwise `null`

Comment: The query statement "[SELECT Id, Name FROM Employee__c WHERE Id =: s.Id]" implicitly returns a list, which is having a result as null. As you are directly assigning result to a variable, you can make it as "List<Employee__c> emp" , to avoid this error.