# Why this strange behavior in the Salesforce debug logs? The query executed twice: 1 returng results and another one returng nothing

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, bulkification

I am writing a trigger to update the child of a parent in case a specific field on the parent has changed.

The problem is I get a query with 0 results. After looking on the debug logs, the SOQL query is executed  twice: Happens once where it returns results, but at the end when it runs again (using the tmpVar1) returns no results.

I guess is something obvious I missing here? Thank you.

I have the code below in case it helps.

```
public static void updatefunction (list <Meeting__c> updateList, map <id, Meeting__c> oldMap )
{
  List <Additional_Participants__c> addp = new list<Additional_Participants__c>();
  for (Meeting__c eachItem :updateList)
  {

    if(eachItem.Contact__c!=null)        
    {
       list <Additional_Participants__c> child = [Select Id, Contact__c 
                                            from Additional_Participants__c 
                                            WHERE Contact__c = :oldMap.get(eachItem.Id).Contact__c 
                                            AND Meeting__c = :oldMap.get(eachItem.Id).Id ];


       child[0].Contact__c = eachItem.Contact_ID_F__c;
       addp.add(child[0]);
       if(!addp.isEmpty())
       {
         update addp;
       }  
     }
   }
 }
```

EDIT: As suggested by Chris, adding below the debug log. It s basically the same debug log where you can see that in the first execution of the query it returns 1 row, and and the end of the debug log, for the same query it says 0 records found..

A) same debug log - beggining of the file (here it gives 1 row as result - as expected)

```
4:39:47.680 (680231341)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[98]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, Contact__c FROM Additional_Participants__c WHERE (Contact__c = :tmpVar1 AND Call_Report__c = :tmpVar2)
14:39:47.697 (697312711)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[98]|Rows:1
14:39:47.697 (697495052)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[98]|String.valueOf(Object)
14:39:47.697 (697587787)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[98]|String.valueOf(Object)
14:39:47.697 (697637389)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[98]|System.debug(ANY)
14:39:47.697 (697652021)|USER_DEBUG|[98]|DEBUG|priiiiiiiinting(Additional_Participants__c:{Id=a3ZM00000009mQrMAI, Contact__c=003D000000jUylBIAS})
14:39:47.697 (697661990)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[98]|System.debug(ANY)
14:39:47.697 (697723515)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[100]|Map<Id,NIF_Call_Report__c>.get(Object)
14:39:47.697 (697779966)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[100]|Map<Id,NIF_Call_Report__c>.get(Object)
14:39:47.697 (697828045)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[100]|Map<Id,NIF_Call_Report__c>.get(Object)
14:39:47.697 (697851676)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[100]|Map<Id,NIF_Call_Report__c>.get(Object)
**14:39:47.698 (698289889)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[100]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, Contact__c FROM Additional_Participants__c WHERE (Contact__c = :tmpVar1 AND Call_Report__c = :tmpVar2)
14:39:47.703 (703606891)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[100]|Rows:1**
14:39:47.737 (737206286)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[104]|List<Additional_Participants__c>.add(Object)
14:39:47.737 (737255046)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[104]|List<Additional_Participants__c>.add(Object)
14:39:47.737 (737267160)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[106]|List<Additional_Participants__c>.isEmpty()
14:39:47.737 (737282992)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[106]|List<Additional_Participants__c>.isEmpty()
14:39:47.737 (737340566)|DML_BEGIN|[108]|Op:Update|Type:Additional_Participants__c|Rows:1
14:39:47.792 (792011173)|DML_END|[108]
```

B) same debug log - end of the file (here is where for the same query it give 0 rows)

```
14:39:47.930 (930824462)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[98]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, Contact__c FROM Additional_Participants__c WHERE (Contact__c = :tmpVar1 AND Call_Report__c = :tmpVar2)
14:39:47.934 (934566794)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[98]|Rows:0
14:39:47.934 (934632317)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[98]|String.valueOf(Object)
14:39:47.934 (934660933)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[98]|String.valueOf(Object)
14:39:47.934 (934682143)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[98]|System.debug(ANY)
14:39:47.934 (934693145)|USER_DEBUG|[98]|DEBUG|priiiiiiiinting()
14:39:47.934 (934699010)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[98]|System.debug(ANY)
14:39:47.934 (934727550)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[100]|Map<Id,NIF_Call_Report__c>.get(Object)
14:39:47.934 (934744833)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[100]|Map<Id,NIF_Call_Report__c>.get(Object)
14:39:47.934 (934767502)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[100]|Map<Id,NIF_Call_Report__c>.get(Object)
14:39:47.934 (934781331)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[100]|Map<Id,NIF_Call_Report__c>.get(Object)
**14:39:47.934 (934977861)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[100]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, Contact__c FROM Additional_Participants__c WHERE (Contact__c = :tmpVar1 AND Call_Report__c = :tmpVar2)
14:39:47.937 (937788201)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[100]|Rows:0**
14:39:47.938 (938033119)|METHOD_EXIT|[11]|01pM0000000HJPe|CreateParticipants.updatefunction(List<NIF_Call_Report__c>, Map<Id,NIF_Call_Report__c>)
14:39:47.938 (938139387)|FATAL_ERROR|System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0
```

Comment: In order to help you we need to see all relevant code and debug logs.   Please post the trigger code and the snipper of the debug log showing both runs of the SOQL query.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you. I have added the debug logs (the trigger is actually calling this APEX class I have pasted.)

Comment: FYI and off topic to your question, this code is not bulk-ready. Deploying this code to production is a time-bomb waiting to go off. At some point, someone will invoke this trigger with more than 100 records in a batch (like data loader), and you will get a governor limit exception. You should not have a SOQL query inside a for loop. Check out this other SFSE question and answer for more details: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices

Comment: As for the specific problem, it could be the effect of another action occurring (workflow). But which trigger events are you attaching your trigger to? Insert, Update, Before, After? Seeing how you invoke this code from the trigger would be useful.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for this. Idneed the trigger is not bulkified, I will have to adapt the logic. In the meantime you are right, it was a worfklow causing the re-run. Now is fixed. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a scenario described in [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) where:

> If the record was updated with workflow field updates, fires before
>   update triggers and after update triggers one more time (and only one
>   more time)

So if something that determines the return value of the query has changed between the first and second runs of the query you will get different results. The best fix is to make the appropriate data checks in the trigger though there are also hacky approaches of just using boolean flags to avoid the second execution.

Comment: Thank you Keith. That was it. A workflow was causing the trigger to run twice.. Used the trick you suggested with the boolean flag and works perfect!