# Bulkify the apex trigger

Tags: trigger

```
trigger SyncContactWithAccount on Contact (before insert, before update) {
    try{
        Map<contact, id> contact = new Map<Contact, id>();
        List<Contact> conList = Trigger.New;    
        List<Account> accList = [select id, Reported_to_country__c from account];

        for(Contact conObj : conList){
            for(Account accObj : accList){
                if(conObj.accountId == accObj.id){
                    conObj.Reported_to_country__c = accObj.Reported_to_country__c; 
                    Update conObj;             
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    catch(Exception ex){
           }
}
```

I dont know How to bulkify the trigger. Plz some body help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [General trigger bulkification - best practices](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices)

Comment: Please read the following stackexchange article: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices

Comment: @lenka create a list of Contact and add the conObj into it in loop. and outside loop of conList update your new Contact list. this is one way, the best way is that have a handler class and call the trigger handler class from your trigger and do your logic their.

Comment: Thanx @Anu & Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how your trigger might look when bulkified:

```
trigger SyncContactWithAccount on Contact (before insert, before update) {

    Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
    for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
        if (c.AccountId != null) {
            if (Trigger.isInsert) {
                // Insert so need to set value
                ids.add(c.AccountId);
            } else if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
                // Update so only set if Account changed
                Contact old = Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id);
                if (old.AccountId != c.AccountId) {
                    ids.add(c.AccountId);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (ids.size() > 0) {
        Map<Id, Account> m = new Map<Id, Account>([
                select Id, Reported_to_country__c
                from Account
                where Id in :ids
                ]);
        for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
            if (c.AccountId != null) {
                c.Reported_to_country__c = m.get(c.AccountId).Reported_to_country__c;
            }
        }
        // No need to update because this is a "before" trigger
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this.

A few points to note:

- Adding triggers that always do work for any change to a standard object is a bad idea because standard objects are often manually modified or modified by other applications adding your work will slow those down or in extreme cases push them into governor limit problems. Hence the test for the update case of whether the `AccountId` has changed as those changes will be rare. If unchanged no SOQL Account query is done at all.
- An easy way to get objects into a map keyed by their ID is to use this [Map constructor](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_ctor).
- As this is a "before" trigger there is no need to update; the changes made will be included automatically.