# Fatal problem with otherwise working code. Please help!

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

this code is meant to suggest a property to a lead based on some of the entered criteria. It is working, but there is a fatal problem.

When I do a mass update of lead records, instead of the trigger handling each one individually, it seems to run the trigger once, extract the needed value for THAT record, and apply that value to EVERY lead that is being updated.

How can I ensure that each lead is handled by the trigger individually during a mass update?

```
trigger calcSum5 on Lead (before insert, before update) 
{
    Lead[] validLeads = new Lead[0];
    Integer rateListIndex = 1;
    Decimal thisRate = 0.00;
    List<Date> leadArrivalDate = new List <Date>();
    List<Date> leadDepartureDate = new List<Date>();
    Set<String> property = new Set<String>();
    Set<Integer> numOfGuests = new Set<Integer>();
    List<String> region = new List<String>();
    Set<String> appProps = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> availProps = new Set<String>();  
    Set<Date> dates = new Set<Date>();
    Map<Date, Decimal> cost = new Map<Date, Decimal>();
    Map<Date, String> undates = new Map<Date, String>();
    Map<String, Decimal> compareRates = new Map<String, Decimal>();


    for(Lead record: Trigger.new)
    {
        if (record.Override_Rate_Total__c == false)
        {
            record.Rate_total__c = 0;

                if(record.Arrival_Date__c != null && record.Departure_Date__c != null && record.Property__c != null)
                {
                    validLeads.add(record);
                    Date tempDate = record.Arrival_Date__c;                
                    String tempProperty = record.Property__c;              
                    Integer tempNumOfGuests = (Integer) (record.of_Adults__c + record.Number_of_Children__c);
                    String tempRegion = record.New_Region__c;
                    Date tempDepartureDate = record.Departure_Date__c;
                    Date tempArrivalDate = record.Arrival_Date__c;
                    property.add(tempProperty);                            
                    numOfGuests.add(tempNumOfGuests);
                    region.add(tempRegion);
                    leadArrivalDate.add(tempArrivalDate);
                    leadDepartureDate.add(tempDepartureDate);

                    //While Lead Arrival Date is less than Lead Departure Date, Add the date to the dates SET and cycle 1 day forward.
                    while(tempDate < record.Departure_Date__c)      
                    {
                        dates.add(tempDate);                               
                        tempDate = tempDate.addDays(1);
                    }

                    //Add 5 guests of slack to compare properties.
                    for (Integer x = 0; x < 5; x++)
                    {
                        tempNumOfGuests++;
                        numOfGuests.add(tempNumOfGuests);
                    }
                }
        }        
    }

    //Query Property rates for the Original Property Inquiry
    for(Property_Rate__c record:[SELECT Property__c, Rate__c,Date__c, Status__c FROM Property_Rate__c WHERE Date__c IN :dates AND Property__c IN :property]) 
    {  
        if (record.Status__c == 'Available' && record.Rate__c != null)                       
        {                                                                                                                                                   
            cost.put(record.Date__c, record.Rate__c);                                        
        }
        else                                                                                                 
        {
            undates.put(record.Date__c, record.Status__c);                                   
        }                                                                                                    
    }

    //Locate Appropriate Properties
    for (Property__c record : [SELECT Name, Region__c, Integer_CanSleep__c FROM Property__c WHERE Integer_CanSleep__c IN: numOfGuests])
    {
        appProps.add(record.Name);   
    }

    //LocateAvailableProperties
    for (Property_Rate__c record : [SELECT Property__r.Name, Property__c, Rate__c, Date__c, Status__c FROM Property_Rate__c WHERE Date__c IN: dates AND Property__c NOT IN: property])
    {
        if (record.Status__c == 'Available')
        {
            availProps.add(record.Property__r.Name);  
        }   
    }   

    //List contains properties that are Available and Appropriate
    List<Property__c> validProperties = new List<Property__c>();


    //Determines scores of each property and saves to compareScores(Property Name, Score)
    Map<String, Integer> compareScores = new Map<String, Integer>();
    Integer score  = 0;

    for (Property__c validPropertiesRecord : [SELECT Name, Id, Region__c, Start_Date__c FROM Property__c WHERE Name IN: availProps AND Name IN: appProps])
    {
        validProperties.add(validPropertiesRecord);
        score = 0;

        if (validPropertiesRecord.Region__c == region.get(0))
        {
            score += 2;
        }
        else  { score += 0; }

        if (validPropertiesRecord.Start_Date__c > (Date.today() - 120))
        {
            score += 1;
        }
        else  { score += 0; }

        compareScores.put(validPropertiesRecord.Id, score);
    }



    /*List contains all validProperties PropertyRate records. Loop divides list index by dateDifference and returns a remainder
    each iteration. As we iterate, we += the rate total (thisRate). Whenever the remainder == 0, we have reached the end of the 
    PropertyRates for any given property. We then save a Map (Property, RateTotal) of each property to search later.*/           
    for (Property_Rate__c propertyRates : [SELECT Property__r.Name, Property__c, Rate__c, Status__c, Date__c FROM Property_Rate__c WHERE Date__c IN: dates AND Property__c IN: validProperties ORDER BY Property__c])
    {
        Integer dateDifference =  leadArrivalDate.get(0).daysBetween(leadDepartureDate.get(0));
        Integer remainder = Math.Mod(rateListIndex, dateDifference);

        if (remainder != 0)
        {
            if (propertyRates.Rate__c != null)
            {
                thisRate += propertyRates.Rate__c;
                rateListIndex++;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if (propertyRates.Rate__c != null)
            {
                thisRate += propertyRates.Rate__c;
                compareRates.put(propertyRates.Property__c, thisRate);
                thisRate = 0.00;
                rateListIndex++;
            }
        }

    }

    //Main Trigger function
    for(Lead record: validLeads)                                       
    {
        Date tempDate = record.Arrival_Date__c;                        //Store Lead arrival Date..                                                               

        while(tempDate < record.Departure_Date__c)                     //While Arrival Date is less than Departure Date...
        {
            Decimal dayRate = cost.get(tempDate);                      //Retreive Rate__c by searching the tempDate..

            if(dayRate != null && undates.isEmpty())                   //if rates != null and dates are available..               
            {
                record.Rate_Total__c += cost.get(tempDate);            //Add dayRate Rate__c to Rate Total from cost MAP and cycle to the next day until Departure Date... Check Availability...
                record.Dates_Available__c = true;
            }
            else if (undates.size() > 0)                               //If there are unavailable dates...                
            {
                cost.clear();                                          
                record.Dates_Available__c = false;

                if (validProperties.isEmpty())                         //If validProperties == 0
                {
                    record.Email = 'alex@alex.norecord';
                    break;
                }
                else if (validProperties.size() == 1)                  //If validProperties == 1
                {

                    Set<String> compareCostsPropertySet = new Set<String>();
                    compareCostsPropertySet = compareRates.keySet();
                    List<String> compareCostsPropertyList = new List<String>();
                    compareCostsPropertyList.addAll(compareCostsPropertySet);

                    record.Property__c = compareCostsPropertyList.get(0);
                    record.Rate_Total__c = compareRates.get(compareCostsPropertyList.get(0));
                    record.Dates_Available__c = true;
                    record.Email = 'na@na.single';

                }

                /* Compare each RateTotal in the list to the RateTotal next to it. Whichever one is greater, should be
                removed from the list until there is only one RateTotal left. We then add the corresponding Property and 
                RateTotal to the lead*/  
                else if (validProperties.size() > 1)                   //If validProperties == 2+
                {
                    Integer value1 = 0;
                    Integer value2 = 0;
                    Set<String> compareScoresPropertySet = new Set<String>();
                    compareScoresPropertySet = compareScores.keySet();
                    List<String> compareScoresPropertyList = new List<String>();
                    compareScoresPropertyList.addAll(compareScoresPropertySet);


                    while(compareScoresPropertyList.size() > 1)
                    {
                        value1 = compareScores.get(compareScoresPropertyList.get(0));
                        value2 = compareScores.get(compareScoresPropertyList.get(1));

                        if (value1 > value2)
                        {
                            compareScoresPropertyList.remove(1);
                        }
                        else if (value2 > value1)
                        {
                            compareScoresPropertyList.remove(0);
                        }
                        else if (value2 == value1)
                        {
                            compareScoresPropertyList.remove(0);
                        }
                    }

                    record.Property__c = compareScoresPropertyList.get(0);
                    record.Rate_Total__c = compareRates.get(compareScoresPropertyList.get(0));
                    record.Dates_Available__c = true;
                    record.Email = 'na@na.multi';


                }



        }

        tempDate = tempDate.addDays(1);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please at least take a look a the basics of [how to bulkify triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code).

Comment: See also http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices

Comment: Thank you Adrian. I will read further into bulkification. But I thought that my trigger was bulkified...I don't have any queries inside for loops. Would you be able to pin-point where in my code bulkification is not in effect?

Thanks again, @AdrianLarson

Comment: http://developer.force.com/BestPractices?categoryId=a0e30000000GuoUAAS

Comment: You are only acting on the first record instead of all records in the new collection.

Comment: No, maybe I misread your code...it is quite a lot to read through.

Comment: To give you an example of the fact that fixing this trigger so it works in bulk is not trivial, you have many collections at the start of the trigger. You may well need a separate set of these collections per Lead to avoid the data for the different Leads being mixed up. This may end up being a re-write; add extra test cases to your tests that check the bulk case.

Comment: @AdrianLarson You no longer think that I'm only acting on the first record?

Comment: @KeithC Okay, what if I just emptied all of the lists, sets, maps at the end of the trigger? After everything has been updated. Would that allow the trigger a fresh start on the next lead?

Comment: @AdrianLarson What if I turned the validLead array into a list. Then I could just append the current record to that list. At the end of the trigger, I could increment the index of the validLead list to update?

Comment: This is pretty complex functionality. The general approach should be to try to map your related collections so that for a given lead, you can always determine the data that is relevant to it.

Comment: The trigger gets passed a set of Leads all at once so no. If your trigger only had a single loop over the Leads then you could move the declarations inside the loop so the collections were initialised per Lead. But you have several loops that seem to rely on values collected earlier. Your trigger is too long or me to have the willpower to give detailed advice: right now from a cursory look it is broken and I doubt there is a quick fix. Good luck.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Would you mind giving me an example of an appropriate mapping for a single lead in an answer?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Or is there a workaround where I can make it impossible to for the trigger to fire on more than one lead at once? If a mass lead update is attempted the trigger will not fire at all?

Comment: @AlexBrigham That would be an extremely poor architectural decision.

Comment: Would it be poor because it could break something? We are a small business and only need this functionality when updating a single record. @AdrianLarson

Comment: It is just not scalable. If you *ever* want to data load leads in your organization or perform any sort of bulk interaction (e.g. parent record updates its children), this trigger will not behave.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I don't have the time to rebuild it right now. But I am interested in learning more about the apex language, so I will launch this to production for now (without bulk updates enabled), and then attempt your solution (separating methods) in sandbox until its possible.

I get that its not ideal, but I do not consider myself an architect. More of a child playing with legos. I am just learning. Thanks for your help Adrian.

Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend breaking out your functionality into `static` methods that **each do one thing**. In practice, that generally means one "how" or many "whats" in your method.

You should always try to keep as much code out of your trigger body as possible, so this will improve your code quality anyway. A more manageable chunk might look like:

```
public static Set<Date> getDates(List<Lead> leads)
{
    List<Date> dates = new List<Date>();
    for (Lead lead : leads)
    {
        dates.addAll(getDates(lead));
    }
    return dates
}
public static Set<Date> getDates(Lead lead)
{
    Date startDate = lead.Arrival_Date__c;
    Date endDate = lead.Departure_Date__c;
    Set<Date> dates = new Set<Date> { startDate };
    while (startDate < endDate)
    {
        startDate = startDate.addDays(1);
        dates.add(startDate);
    }
    return dates;
}
```

Other stub examples might look like:

```
public static List<Property_Rate__c > queryProperties(Set<Date> dates, Set<Id> propertyIds)
{
    return [QUERY];
}
```

As an aside, you have some code that does absolutely nothing like:

```
else { score += 0; }
```

What does this accomplish? Just remove it.

Comment: So these static methods should be written in apex classes and then just called from the trigger?

Comment: Correct. Eventually you should get to a point where you have one method into which you pass the leads, e.g. `LeadServices.calculateRates(trigger.new);` or similar.

Comment: Just my opinion, but I'd also be inclined to recommend combining all of those queries into a single dynamic query, then sorting to get the results you're looking for. That's a lot of queries to execute each time the trigger is called. Let one of your methods do the sorting for you.

Comment: Yes and they would likely also need to be in some sort of map, e.g. `Map<Id, List<Property_Rate__c>> propertyToRates`.