# How to update field and insert record at same time?

Tags: trigger

I created a trigger and also it is updating the field after inserting the record. **But my concern is i am using query inside for loop so it is hitting the governor limit.**
As i am new to salesforce i am not able to do outside for loop

```
trigger trg on object1 (after update) {

for ( object1 o  : trigger.new)
    {
if(o.field1 = 'text')
 {
     object2 o2 = new object2();
     o2.Name = 'xyz';
     o2.Email = o.email;
     insert o2;
    object1  ob1 = [Select Field1,field2 from Object1 where id =: o.id] ;
     ob1.field2 = o2.id;
     update ob1;
  }

}

}
```

Comment: oh dear, you are doing soql and DML inside a for loop.  This will run into governor issues and definitely is not best practice.  You need to bulkify your trigger

Comment: Maybe start by reading [General trigger bulkification - best practices](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/47469/102)

Comment: I would recommend taking a step back a bit and go through some trailhead. https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, it sounds like you need to spend a bit of time learning some of the basics.

The process would be something like:

- perform action on a before trigger, not after.  This means you can just assign the value to field2 without having to perform a DML operation.
- iterate through records within the trigger and create a Map of object2 records you'd like to insert.  The map should use the ID of the object1 record as a key so you know which ones to associate it with.
- once the object2 records have been inserted, iterate over the object1 records and update field2 accordingly

Your code would look something like this:

```
trigger trg on object1 (before update) {

// Define a map of object2 records we want to create
Map<Id, object2> object2ToInsert = new Map<Id, object2>();
for ( object1 o  : trigger.new)
{
    if(o.field1 = 'text')
    {
        // Add the o2 record to the map rather than inserting it straight away
        object2 o2 = new object2(Name = ‘xyz’, Email = o.email);
        object2ToInsert.add(o.Id, o2);
    }
}

// If we have some object2 records to insert, do it
if(!object2ToInsert.isEmpty())
{
    insert object2ToInsert.values();

    // Then go through the trigger to update object1 records where required
    for ( object1 o  : trigger.new)
    {
        if(object2ToInsert.containsKey(o.id))
        {
            o.field2 = object2ToInsert.get(o.id).id;
        }
        // Note: because we used a before trigger, we don’t need to do DML for the object1 update
    }
}
```