# Error:Loop must iterate over a collection type: User

Tags: apex, list, set, collection, for

I am getting error saying'Loop must iterate over a collection type: User'.I am not able to find what actually error wants to say.

```
List<User> listUserDeactivate = new List<User>();
Set<ID> userDeactSet = new Set<ID>();
for(user u : listUserDeactivate){
    try{
        System.debug(':::::::inside try block ::::::::'+u);
        if(u!=null && !u.isEmpty()){

            //List<Database.SaveResult> results= Database.update(listUserDeactivate);
            for (user deactivateuser : u) {
                deactivateuser.IsActive = false;
            }
            update u;        
            System.debug(':::::::inside try block 2 ::::::::'+u);          
        }
        //System.debug(':::::::inside try block 2 ::::::::'+results);

    }catch(exception e) {

        System.debug('value of ids of deactivation users ::::: '+u);
        Set<Id> resultIds = (new Map<Id,User>(u)).keySet();
        System.debug('value of ids of exception users ::::: '+resultIds);
        userDeactSet.add(resultIds);          
    }                
}
```

Comment: Your list has no data in it when your loop begins. So, there is nothing to loop through.

Comment: This is just example.I have data in list.Just for reference i kept like above.

Comment: You should move `try`/`catch` block and `dml` all out of the `for` loop. Take a look at some of the [excellent questions](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices) on our exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error  in this line

```
for (user deactivateuser : u) {
       deactivateuser.IsActive = false;
 }
```

Here `u` is single record and you are tring to iterate ..

You can iterate list in for loop

---

Just do that `u.IsActive  = false`..  Also you need to perform update DML outside of for loop

Create a list, once you make `u.IsActive  = false` add record to list and outside of for loop perform DML

```
List<User> listUserToUpdate = new List<User>();
for(user u : listUserDeactivate){
    u.IsActive  = false;
    listUserToUpdate.add(u);
}

try{
    update listUserToUpdate;

}catch(exception e) {

             //other codes here
}
```

---

instead try catch use `Database.upsert` for DML and store result in `Database.SaveResult` and get all the falut records

```
List<Database.SaveResult> updateResults;
updateResults = Database.upsert(listUserToUpdate, false);
for(Integer i=0;i<updateResults.size();i++){

   if (!updateResults.get(i).isSuccess()){
                // DML operation failed
                userDeactSet.add(listUserToUpdate.get(i).Id); 
                system.debug('Failed ID'+listUserToUpdate.get(i).Id);

    }
 }
system.debug('--------check---userDeactSet--'+userDeactSet);
```

Comment: Got it for one record issue but how can i update dml outside of for loop as i need to update it.I am using try - catch block and i need to update inside try block.Any alternative.

Comment: @RobertBarnett check my updated ans'

Comment: @Ratan-I am using try catch statement inside for loop.So how can i keep dml statement outside of outer for loop (outside try-catch)

Comment: @RobertBarnett check my updated ans

Comment: But this way it is causing issue when i am running in a batch class with size= 200.It is not looping one user at a time to update user records.It is going to for loop as a batch of 200 user records and if any records has exception then whole batch goes to catch block.

Comment: @RobertBarnett you may need to use `Database.SaveResult` to get all the false user record id. Check my updated Ans

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34866/discussion-between-robert-barnett-and-ratan).

Comment: I am able to get id of failed records which solved my problem easily and made my code shorter.