# insert and updat unittest not covering. adderror why?

Tags: trigger, unit-test, dml, try-catch

Why is my catch not working on the adderror on contentversion see:

```
trigger NoteOnContentversion on ContentVersion (before insert, before update) {
     for (ContentVersion c : Trigger.new)  {
        if (c.ContentDocumentId != null) {
            for (ContentDocumentLink link : [
                SELECT LinkedEntityId
                FROM ContentDocumentLink
                WHERE ContentDocumentId = :c.ContentDocumentId
            ]){
                Id parentId = link.LinkedEntityId;
                System.debug('link.LinkedEntityId '+ link);

                Boolean isOrderRegel = parentId.getSObjectType() == Orderregel__c.SObjectType;

                if (isOrderRegel && Approval.isLocked(parentId)){
                  c.addError('Approval pending. You do not have the permission to edit this note, please contact your administrator.');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Test class**

```
@IsTest(seeAllData=false)
private class TestNoteOnContentversion {

    @IsTest 
    static void refuse_shouldAddError_whenOrderregelIsLocked() {
        // arrange
        Account acc = new Account(
            Name = 'TEST_ACCT', 
            Account_Status_DS__c = 'Status'
        );
        insert acc;

        Orderregel__c orderregel = new Orderregel__c(
            Account__c = acc.Id,
            Orderbegindatum__c = Date.today()
        );

        insert orderregel;

        ContentVersion content=new ContentVersion(); 
        content.Title='Header_Picture1'; 
        content.PathOnClient='/' + content.Title + '.jpg'; 
        Blob bodyBlob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test ContentVersion Body'); 
        content.VersionData=bodyBlob; 
        //content.LinkedEntityId=sub.id;
        content.origin = 'H';
        insert content;

        ContentDocumentLink contentlink=new ContentDocumentLink();
        contentlink.LinkedEntityId=acc.id;
        contentlink.contentdocumentid=[select contentdocumentid from contentversion where id =: content.id].contentdocumentid;
        contentlink.ShareType = 'V';

        //insert contentlink;

        List<Account> accts = [SELECT Id from Account WHERE Name = 'TEST_ACCT'];

        //lock the account record.
        Approval.LockResult[] lrList = Approval.lock(accts, false);

        Test.startTest();
        try { 
              insert contentlink;
            }
        catch (Exception dmx) 
        { 
           Boolean expectedExceptionThrown = dmx.getMessage().contains('Approval pending. You do not have the permission to edit this note, please contact your administrator.') ? true : false; 
           System.assertEquals(expectedExceptionThrown, true);  
        }
        Test.stopTest();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already provided the guidance yesterday at your last question

[Test Class coverage for trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/156869/test-class-coverage-for-trigger/156951#156951)

Here, it can be seen that, you have not created Link record before locking Account record.

So, take this steps:

1. Create ContentDocumentlink record.
2. Lock Orderregel__c record where content document is under that Orderregel__c.
3. Update the ContentDocument.

You will definitely get error to trap.

Comment: thanks for your help. On the ContentDocument it did work indeed, but im a little confused on the contentversion. Do you mean with 1. insert contentlink; 2. Approval.LockResult[] lrList = Approval.lock(accts, false);  3. update ContentDocument;?  this last one isnt on the Contentversion could you please clarify whats wrong?

Comment: In your trigger you are locking Orderregel__c, but in test class you are locking Account... you are blindly copy & pasting the code without using the logic

Comment: your right so in this case i need to update content right? Or is it contentlink?

Comment: update content..

Comment: ok if i use: Approval.LockResult[] lrList = Approval.lock(Orderregel__c, false); i get variable does not exist im a little in the dark here?