# Compile Error on Map: Variable WhoId Doesn't Exist

Tags: apex, trigger, apex-variable

Got the compile error for the snippet of code below. Says variable record.whoId (bolded) doesn't exist. Tried adding more brackets to the if statement, capitalizing WhoId and didn't work. Here's the full code from @AdrianLarson - [System.QueryException: List has no rows - How can I tie Events created for qualified Contacts to Opps created from the Contact?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158609/system-queryexception-list-has-no-rows-how-can-i-tie-events-created-for-quali/159926?noredirect=1#comment237372_159926)

```
Map<Id, List<Event>> events = new Map<Id, List<Event>>();
for (Event event : [
    SELECT WhoId FROM Event
    WHERE WhoId IN :contactIds
    AND WhatId = null
    AND Type = 'MQL'
]){
    if (!events.containsKey(record.WhoId))
        events.put(**record.WhoId**, new List<Event>());
    events.get(whoId).add(event);
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with your current code (including the loop definition). Comments are not for clutter and harder for other users to notice. :)

Comment: Sorry! I'm new. Will do

Comment: No worries. That's why I'm trying to nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: Gonna clear out this thread now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looping over a `List<Event>`, you'll need to pull the `WhoId` from the loop record:

```
for (Event record : [SELECT WhoId, ... FROM Event WHERE ...])
{
    if (!events.containsKey(record.WhoId))
        events.put(record.WhoId, new List<Event>());
    events.get(record.WhoId).add(record);
}
```

The documentation isn't great here, but the syntax when you declare a `for` loop is:

> `for (`*`loop_variable_type`**`loop_variable_name`*`:`*`loop_collection`*)

In the code I have above:

- the `loop_variable_type` is `Event`
- the `loop_variable_name` is `record`
- the `loop_collection` is the query

In your code, your `loop_variable_name` is `event`, so the variable `record` is not defined in scope. Either rename your loop variable to `record`, or change the code references inside to `event`.

Comment: I always recommend *not* using the name of an object for any class, class member, or variable. It makes it a lot easier to have bad things happen.

Comment: @sfdcfox And it's just sensible practice to name single records `record` and collections `records` when there's little chance of naming collisions.